# Change FAB background color on PreL device

Tags: android, android-support-library, floating-action-button

I want to know If I'm using `Android Support Library` and using the `FloatingActionButton` element then how do I change the background color on **PreL** devices.

Because the options provided by `support library` i.e

```
app:tint="color"
app:backgroundTint="color"
```

works on `api > 21`.
Also I don't want to change my `Accent color` rather I want to change the background color of this particular `fab` and want to add backward compatibility.

Your suggestions is highly appreciated.

Comment: can you tell me which support library version are you using ??

Comment: @Ironman I'm using support library 23.4.0, I have tried with V 24.1.1 but it's the same

Comment: try to update your library.

Comment: @Ironman the function `setBackgroundTint` is available for Api above 21. How come updating library will solve this issue? Please explain

Comment: I know this : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199757  but may be updated version can solve this issue if developer team is work on it so ??